# Algebraic reason for deriving similarity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the book titled 'Number, Shape, and Symmetry' by  'Diane herrmann, 
Paul sally ' there is a game called Triangle game that is concerned 
with finding different ways of filling the 3 sides of a triangles and 
its 3 vertices by numbers from 1 to 6 such that the sum is the same.
The same is freely available at the website at : https://www.math.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/courses/MAT189-Chapters0and1.pdf

Based on the approach of the book for the case where the sum is 9, I 
have arrived at the following algebraic solution for arriving at all 
possible cases with sums as 9, 10, 11,12 as follows:
(Please note that I am following book's notn. for the vertices and sides in ck order as : a,b,c,d,e,f.)

So, 3S = (a+b+c)+(c+d+e)+(e+f+a) 
=>  3S = (a+c+e) + 21           --- eqn. (1)

As the lhs is a multiple of 3, so the quantity (a+c+e = 'sum of 
values of vertices') should also be a multiple of 3.

Now, need to convert the rhs of eqn. (1) into a form divisible by 3, so taking use of the fact that sum and differences of two multiples of 3 are also multiple of 3; convert the rhs of eqn. (1) into a form that has only a single variable, let 'a'.

So, have the differences (c-a) & (e-a), irrespective of difference being positive or negative. The sum of (c-a) + (e-a) => c +e -2a. For the sum to be 'positive' and a multiple of 3, c + e = 3k +2a, & 'k' a value in the set {1,2,3}.

The rhs of eqn. (1) now is : 3(k + a + 7) --- eqn. (2)

The minimum value of k=1 leads to :

(i) a=1 (c,e belongs_to_the_set {2,3}),

(ii) a=2 (c,e belongs_to_the_set {3,4}),

(iii) a=3 (c,e belongs_to_the_set {4,5}),

(iv) a=4 (c,e belongs_to_the_set {5,6}).

The second integer value of k=2 leads to :

(v) c+e = 6 +2a, & possible values of a being 1 (c,e belongs_to_the_set {3,5} or {6,2}),

(vi) a=2 (c,e belongs_to_the_set {4,6}).

The third integer value of k=3 leads to :

(vii) c+e = 9 +2a, & possible values of a being 1 (c,e belongs_to_the_set {5,6}).

Further, these configurations lead to four possible values of S, i.e.

case (i)  : 3S = (1 + 2 +3) +21     => S = 9

case (ii) : 3S = (2 + 3/4 +4/3) +21 => S = 10  ------- (here, / denotes 'or')

case (iii): 3S = (3 + 4/5 +5/4) +21 => S = 11

case (iv) : 3S = (4 + 5/6 + 6/5) +21 => S = 12

case (v)  : 3S = (1 + 3/5 +5/3) +21 => S = 10 , or (1 + 2/6 +6/2) +21 => S = 10

case (vi) : 3S = (2 + 4/6 +6/4) +21 => S = 11

case (vii): 3S = (1 + 5/6 +6/5) +21 => S = 11

The other points' (side points) values can be found accordingly, by fixing one value to 'c' & another value to 'e'. The opposite set of values for 'c' & 'e' will be a matter of symmetry action in groups.

case (i)  : S = 9,  a=1, c=2, e=3 => b=6, d=4, f=5.

case (ii) : S = 10, a=2, c=3, e=4 => d,f : unable to find.

case (iii): S = 11, a=3, c=4, e=5 => f : unable to find.

case (iv) : S = 12, a=4, c=5, e=6 => b=3, d=1, f=2.

case (v)  : S = 10, a=1, c=3, e=5 => b=6, d=2, f=4; -or- a=1,c=2,e=6

=> b:unable to find.

case (vi) : S = 11, a=2, c=4, e=6 => b=5, d=1, f=3.

case (vii): S = 11, a=1, c=5, e=6 => d,f : unable to find.

The cases that lead to viable solutions (i.e., a fixed value of sum 
S) are : (i), (iv), (v), (vi) -- with fixed sum value (S) being 9, 12, 10, 11 respectively.

The issue starts with the question asked in paragraphs on page 20 & 21, where text asks to get S = 11, 12 from S = 9, 10 with the help of reflections, rotations, & duality.

In the diagram below, I have stated the cases for similarity between case for S=9 & S=12; & the similarity between S=10 & S=11. In particular, the points in between are the same in each of the 2 cases.

[image]
Having failed (except by logic) to find one, my question is to request an algebraic reason for this preservation of values (in a given triple comprised of a side & two vertex points -to- a vertex & two side points), i.e. something similar to the algebraic explanation above or may be advanced also, but preferably having an algebraic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\triangle ABC$ put the number $a$ at $A,  \; b$ at $B, \; c$ at $C.$ And put  number $d$ on side $AB,\; e$ on $BC,\; f$ on $CA ,$ with the sums of the $3$ numbers on each of the sides being equal to each other. So $$a+d+b=b+e+c=c+f+a.$$ Now on $\triangle A'B'C'$ put $e$ at $A',\; f $ at $B',\;  d$ at $C',$ and put  $a$ on side $B'C',\; b$ on  $C'A',\; c$ on  $A'B'.$ We have $$a+d+b=b+e+c\implies a+d=e+c\implies a+d+f=e+c+f.$$  Now $a+d+f$ is the sum of the  numbers on $B'C'$ while $e+c+f$ is the sum of the numbers on $A'B',$ so these sums are equal.

Similarly, because $b+e+c=c+f+a\implies b+e=f+a\implies  b+e+d=f+a+d, $ the sums on sides $C'A'$ and $B'C'$ are also equal.

Comment: Is there any branch of maths or algorithms that handles such problems. A formal approach, if exists would assist greatly in framing solutions.